# PHP dar refresh em uma página

Tags: php

Existe uma maneira de dar `refresh` a uma página no meu exemplo:

Pagina login > manda dados para o `processa.php` > manda para um menu

Ás vezes quando chega ao processa, fica "preso" e então eu queria saber de uma maneira de isso não acontecer.

Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria algo como:

```
header("Refresh: 20; url = menu.php");
```

Você colocando Refresh em 20, se travar ele já vai sair

Answer (score 6):

Se eu entendi corretamente, isso é simples de fazer com o PHP:

```php
header("Refresh: 0");
```

Isso irá recarregar sua página atual, e se você precisar redirecionar para outra página, use o código abaixo:

```php
header("Refresh: 0; url=pagina2.php");
```

Obs.: Uma discussão sobre o mesmo assunto pode ser encontrada (em inglês) no link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383371/refresh-a-page-using-php

Comment: Resolvido. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

da uma olhada http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php

no seu caso eu tentaria algo como

```
header("Refresh:5");//recarrega em 5 segundos
```

mas vc ñ tem como descobrir pq esta parando?

Answer (score -4):

Na página **processa.php** adicionar:

`$_SESSION['expirar'] = time();`

Na página **menu** adicionar o codigo:

```
//faz o refresh da página em 5 min e 5 segundos

header("Refresh:305");

// tempo em que a sessão ficará logada. Não pode ser superior ao refresh 

$idletime = 300; 

//Valida se o tempo da sessão é maior que 5 min, destrói todas as sessões e redireciona para a pagina inicial.
// Caso o tempo de inatividade seja menor que 5 min, nada ocorrerá.

if (time() - $_SESSION['expirar'] > $idletime) {
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
    header("Location: ../index.html");
} else {
    $_SESSION['expirar'] = time();
}
```

Continue com o restante do seu código logo abaixo.

Esta é a forma mais segura que o `header("Refresh:305");` para tratar a inatividade de um site!